# finatra/examples/twitter-clone: Testing the firebase client

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, guice, finagle, finatra

In the [`twitter-clone`](https://github.com/twitter/finatra/tree/develop/examples/twitter-clone) example, the following firebase client is defined:

```
@Singleton
class FirebaseClient @Inject()(
  httpClient: HttpClient,
  mapper: FinatraObjectMapper) {

// ...

}
```

I would like to write a test that uses this class. The problem I have is that I cannot simply instanciate a variable of this class in my test code:

```
class FirebaseClientTest extends ??? {
    val firebaseClient: FirebaseClient = new FirebaseClient(???, ???)
}
```

Since I don't know how an instance of `HttpClient` and `FinatraObjectMapper` is actually created in the production code. I could try to create these objects manually, but this adds boilerplate which I'd like to avoid.

How can I get an instance of `FirebaseClient` by the magic of the dependecy injection mechanisms used in Finatra?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is detailed in the [finatra-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/finatra-users/krv98Vs1_SM) group. I'm summarizing it here for the sake of completeness.

Basically instances that require dependencies to be injected can be obtained by using the `TestInjector` class. For the problem at hand, a `FirebaseClient` instance can be obtained as follows:

```
class FirebaseClientTest extends SomeClassOfATestFramework {

    val injector = TestInjector(FirebaseClientModule)

    val firebaseClient: FirebaseClient = injector.instance[FirebaseClient]
}
```